# Selecting Only The Latest Version Of A Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table schema with ID, Title, Date

and data looks something like this:

```
1  The title1    2011-04-05 00:00:00.000
2  Another title 2011-04-11 00:00:00.000
3  The title1    2011-04-11 16:49:23.633
4  The title1    2011-04-11 00:00:00.000
```

I need help with sql to give me the latest date of each title. 
So the output for the above data is

```
2  Another title 2011-04-11 00:00:00.000
3  The title1    2011-04-11 16:49:23.633
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select mytable.Title, MAX(mytable.Date)
from mytable
group by mytable.Title
```

Answer (score 5):

```
select id,title,date from [schema]
where title in (select title from [schema] group by title having date=max(date))
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

Look at Max and group by in Books online

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Including an [Aggregated Column's Related Values](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/including-an-aggregated-column-s-related), there are several ways to accomplish this

One way would be

```
select t1.* from(
select Title, Max(Date) as MaxDate
From YourTable
group by Title) t2
join YourTable t1 on t2.Title = t1.Title
and t1.Date = t2.MaxDAte
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table name is `mytable`:

```
select 
  tbl.ID, tbl.Title, tbl.Date
from 
  mytable tbl join
  (select Title, max(Date) Date
   from mytable) maxes on tbl.Date = maxes.Date and tbl.Title = maxes.Title
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming at least SQL Server 2005:

```
SELECT ID, Title, [Date]
    FROM (SELECT ID, Title, [Date],
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Title ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS RowNum
              FROM YourTable
         ) t
    WHERE t.RowNum = 1
```